# WP Rest Api GET method restriction on route, but POST method also works

Tags: plugins, rest-api, http

I'm doing some basic API testing and notice that restricting my new route to GET doesn't work. POST requests also go though using Postman. (PUT, PATCH, DELETE do not however, displaying a "no matching route/method" error):

```
function displayDummyData() {
  return 'dummy data'; // responds 'dummy data' on POST request
}

function checkIfAnyone() {
  return true;
}


function registerDummyRoute() {
  register_rest_route('wp/v2', 'tut', [
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'displayDummyData',
    'permission_callback' => 'checkIfAnyone'
  ]);
}
add_action('rest_api_init', 'registerDummyRoute');
```

How can I restrict this route to only GET requests?

Comment: I copied your _exact_ code and when I sent a POST request and received the error "No route was found matching the URL and request method".

Comment: Also, you should not be using `wp/v2` as your namespace. That's reserved for the core APIs and using it defeats the entire purpose of using namespaces.